# Checking if a geocoordinate point is land or ocean with cartopy?

Tags: cartopy

I want to know given a latitude and longitude if a coordinate is land or sea

According to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235133/checking-if-a-geocoordinate-point-is-land-or-ocean

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
bm = Basemap()   # default: projection='cyl'
print bm.is_land(99.675, 13.104)  #True
print bm.is_land(100.539, 13.104)  #False
```

The problem is that basemap is deprecated. how di perform this with cartopy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A question which deals with point containment testing of country geometries using cartopy can be found at [Polygon containment test in matplotlib artist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399704/polygon-containment-test-in-matplotlib-artist).

Cartopy has the tools to achieve this, but there is no built-in method such as "is_land". Instead, you need to get hold of the appropriate geometry data, and query that using standard shapely predicates.

```
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import shapely.geometry as sgeom
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.prepared import prep

land_shp_fname = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='50m',
                                       category='physical', name='land')

land_geom = unary_union(list(shpreader.Reader(land_shp_fname).geometries()))
land = prep(land_geom)

def is_land(x, y):
    return land.contains(sgeom.Point(x, y))
```

This gives the expected results for two sample points:

```
>>> print(is_land(0, 0))
False
>>> print(is_land(0, 10))
True
```

If you have access to it, fiona will make this easier (and snappier):

```
import fiona
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import shapely.geometry as sgeom
from shapely.prepared import prep

geoms = fiona.open(
            shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='50m',
                                    category='physical', name='land'))

land_geom = sgeom.MultiPolygon([sgeom.shape(geom['geometry'])
                                for geom in geoms])

land = prep(land_geom)
```

Finally, I produced (back in 2011) the shapely.vectorized functionality to speed up this kind of operation when testing *many* points at the same time. The code is available as a gist at https://gist.github.com/pelson/9785576, and produces the following proof-of-concept for testing land containment for the UK:

[image: uk_containment]

Another tool you may be interested in reading about is geopandas, as this kind of containment testing is one of its core capabilities.

Comment: I had a heck of a time getting all of the cartopy dependencies installed. I might add a little blurb warning users of your answer that it's not just a straight-forward pip install.

Comment: Now I am discovering those dependencies have a setup that is non-trivial, even after following the sparse directions on the GEOS and cartopy web-pages. Then after installation of all requirements, imports error out unless you install even more dependencies that are not listed anywhere except on this github issue: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1239