# Why is checking if a geopoint is on land failing in cartopy?

Tags: cartopy

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062502/1518684), I tried to check if the coordinate pair (longitude, latitude) = (-3.4066095486248327, 51.38747051763357) represents a location on land. Here is my code:

```
import fiona
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import shapely.geometry as sgeom
from shapely.prepared import prep
geoms = fiona.open(shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='10m', category='physical', name='land'))
land_geom = sgeom.MultiPolygon([sgeom.shape(geom['geometry']) for geom in geoms])
land = prep(land_geom)

x = -3.4066095486248327
y = 51.38747051763357

print(land.contains(sgeom.Point(x, y)))
```

The result is `False` even though the point is on land, which I checked using [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B023'14.9%22N+3%C2%B024'23.8%22W/@51.3874738,-3.4087982,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d51.3874705!4d-3.4066095). I also checked if `x` and `y` should switch places in `sgeom.Point(x, y)`, but that didn't work out as the result was still `False`.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That point is very close to the coast. You have used the 1:10 million scale coastline as the "truth" about where the coastline is, but at this scale that point is indeed not on land, it is just off the coast:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


x = -3.4066095486248327
y = 51.38747051763357

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution="10m")
ax.scatter([x], [y], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
# Land is top half, sea is bottom half of the domain
ax.set_extent([x-.1, x+.1, y-.1, y+.1], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()
```

[image: point plotted with coastline]

If you want to get this right on such scales then you will need to use a more accurate representation of the coastline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I find a more accurate representation of the coastline?

Comment: Well, that part is up to you and the needs of you application. For this method what you need is a more accurate shapefile. You could try https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html and see if that suits, but what works for you will depend on the region(s) you want to be able to do this test in.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this, so I appreciate all the advice and hints.