# draw a population density map for the world in python matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a dictionary of countries (by their 2 letter country code), and the population density of each country.

I'd like to create a map with each country colored according to a color bar of density, with the country boundries drawn.

I've tried using the basemap package, like in [this notebook](http://introtopython.org/visualization_earthquakes.html#simple_map)

This [piece of code](https://gist.github.com/adience-code/5658956b26fa4ab64ff9) works for the US countries. But I want to do it worldwide.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397022/fill-countries-in-python-basemap

Comment: I think this [post](http://ramiro.org/notebook/basemap-choropleth/) could be really useful. ![](http://i4.tietuku.com/08e327b15bba3a22.png) It use shapefile of each countries to define the contour boundaries.