# fill in each zip-code with a different color for basemap of Matplotlib in Python 3.2

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, python-3.2, matplotlib-basemap

I am working on coloring zip-code polygon in a basemap of Matplotlib in Python 3.2.

I need to fill in each zip-code with a different color.

The zip-code information comes from shapefile.

I cannot find solutions at: 
http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you are using to plot the map.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill countries in python basemap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397022/fill-countries-in-python-basemap)

Answer (score 4):

[Basemap](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) has a pretty handy way to read in a shapefile.

```
m = Basemap()
m.readshapefile('file_without_extension', 'name')
```

You can then access information on the shapefile with `m.name` and `m.name_info`.

Then create the dataframe you want to use for color info.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

zipdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'shapes': [Polygon(np.array(shape), True) for shape in m.name],
    'zip': [area['zip'] for area in m.name_info]
})
```

If you want to include information for coloring that is not included in the shapefile, merge that other info with the DataFrame you just created.

```
zipdf = zipdf.merge(other_df, how='right', on='zip')
```

Now for actually coloring the map, I used a colormap that takes values for rental prices in the zipcode, so I'll show that.

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
pc = PatchCollection(zipdf['shapes'], zorder=2)
norm = colors.Normalize()

pc.set_facecolor(cmap(norm(zipdf['price'].values)))
ax.add_collection(pc)

cmapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
cmapper.set_array(zipdf['price'])
plt.colorbar(cmapper)

plt.show()
```

For a bit more on this, check out [Creating Attractive and Informative Map Visualisations in Python with Basemap](http://www.datadependence.com/2016/06/creating-map-visualisations-in-python) from Data Dependence.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the above answer, you can find the aforementioned 'file without extension' for us zip codes [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2019-2010-nation-u-s-2010-census-5-digit-zip-code-tabulation-area-zcta5-na)